# Three.js: Cannot change Boolean value in onLoad function

Tags: javascript, three.js, boolean

I am using the Three.js Loading Manager to start and stop my `requestionAnimationFrame` animation loop. I have this:

```
var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var isLoaded = new Boolean();

    loadingManager.onLoad = function () {
        isLoaded = true;
    };

    function startAnimationLoop() {
      if (!runAnimation) {
        runAnimation= animationDisplay.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    }

    function stopAnimationLoop() {
      if (runAnimation) {
        animationDisplay.cancelAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
        runAnimation= undefined;
      }
    }
```

And this is what's in the render loop:

```
if (isLoaded == true) {
  startAnimationLoop(); //not working
 } else if (isLoaded == false) {
  stopAnimationLoop();
}
```

It seems `isLoaded` has not been set to true in the `onLoad` function as the animation loop does not start. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to make object of OBJLoader

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( loadingManager );
```

then you need to call load function

```
loader.load( 'loadingManager', function ( object ) { }
```

refer this [three.js doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager)

Comment: I have this already, I did not include it because it did not relate to my question.

Comment: Put an alert in onload to see, if onload is working?